# Insert issue with arrays

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dictionary, insert

Iam new to vc++.Iam trying to write program using map::insert function in below code

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
int arr[3] ={0,1,2};
map <int, int[3]> mymap;
std::map<int,int[3]>::iterator it = mymap.begin();
mymap.insert(it,std::make_pair(1,arr));
}
```

Iam getting 
error C2664: 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> std::_Tree<_Traits>::insert(std::pair &&)' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>' to 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &&'

can you please give solution how to solve this error

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

storing C array is not a good idea, use `std::array` instead.

```
using Arr = std::array<int, 3>;
Arr arr = { 0, 1, 2 };
std::map <int, Arr> mymap;
auto it = mymap.begin( );
mymap.insert( it, std::make_pair( 1, arr ) );
```

Comment: error C2039: 'array' : is not a member of 'std' 
error C2059: syntax error : '{'
error C2065: 'Arr' : undeclared identifier 
error C2065: 'Arr' : undeclared identifier
error C2065: 'Arr' : undeclared identifier
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{' 
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}' 
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '=' 
error C2873: 'Arr' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration
error C2923: 'std::map' : 'Arr' is not a valid template type argument for parameter '_Ty'

Comment: Two things, you need to compile with c++11 support. it looks like it is already ok because the error do not complains about the `using` syntax. Then, as everything else in the standard library, you need to include the right header, `#include <array>`

Comment: after including #include <array> iam facing same errors..please explain in detail because iam new to c++....